# Не найден указанный модуль. В 1 случае из 20

Tags: c#, .net, исключения, dll

Моя программа использует функции из моей библиотеки на C++/CLI. dll-ка всегда находится в одной папке с exe'шником. Программа без проблем запускается на ~20 различных компютерах (ОС от Win7 до 10). Но вчера установив программу на компьютер с Win7 поймал такое исключение при попытке использовать функционал dll-ки:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MyDllName.dll' or one of its dependencies. Не найден указанный
>   модуль.

По началу подумал что не хватает каких-то зависимостей у dll-ки. Проверил Dependensy Walker'ом -всё зависимые dll на месте. 
Причём если удалить библиотеку из папки с программой то выдаст уже немного другую ошибку:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyDllName, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Как исправить данную ошибку? ну или хотя бы в какую сторону копать?

PS: Попробовал воспроизвести ошибку на виртуалке: поставил такую же ос, .Net. Создал пользователя с минимальными правами. Запустил программу-всё норм.

Comment: Копайте: Properties - Security - Permissions

Comment: @Igor на папку с программой у юзера полный доступ.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить программу используя "Run as Administrator".

Comment: @Igor сегодня уже не получится т.к. к этому нужно привлекать локальных администраторов, чей рабочий день уже закончен. Однако вот ещё такой момент: закинул в папку с программой все системные dll-ки от которых зависит моя библиотека и всё равно та же ошибка...
Если программа корректно отработает при запуске от администратора, то что тогда? В будущем программа при запуске не должна требовать повышения прав до администратора. Какие ещё могут быть настройки, которые могут повлиять на работу программы?

Comment: Это, конечно, на данный момент - гадание на кофейной гуще. Давайте сначала попробуем. DLL на старте никакие файлы не пишет, из реестра ничего не читает?

Comment: Вот еще:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411020

Comment: Добавьте логирование. В исключении гляньте в fusion log, там обычно важная информация о том, что пыталась сделать система, и что у неё не получилось. Но это если проблема в .NET-части.

Comment: А можете запустить процесс под отладчиком на удалённой машине?

Comment: DLL на старте ничего в файлы не пишет и из реестра не читает, однако обращается к WinAPI (диалоги) и драйверам (печать).
Запуск под отладчиком невозможен, т.к. прямого доступа к удалённой машине нет.